# How to disable past dates with Strapi (Backend)

Tags: backend, strapi

Do you have any tips how can I disable the past dates on input date for forms with Strapi (only backend, not frontend).
I don't have any exact idea and I'm looking for an answer.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Compare the `data.createdAt` object field with the current time, which you can get by constructing a new `Date` object.

```js
const createdDate = new Date(data.createdAt);
const currentDate = new Date():

if(createdDate.getTime() < currentDate.getTime()) {
 // do something
};
```

Answer (score 0):

With the strapi date field, its not possible to restrict calendar to disable past dates on ui. However you can handle it on the hooks(beforeCreate and beforeUpdate). There you can validate if the date is past or present.if its past dates, you can throw a valid error message on FE. Here is a sample code how to use beforeCreate and beforeUpdate hooks inside `content-types/<content-type>/lifecycles.js`:

```
const { ForbiddenError } = require('@strapi/utils').errors;
async function checkForValidData(data, id) { 
//your code to test the dates.
//if failed  - throw new ForbiddenError("past dates are not allowed");
}

module.exports = {
  async beforeCreate(event) {
    const data = event.params.data;

    await checkForValidData(data);
  },
  async beforeUpdate(event) {
    const { where, data } = event.params;
    const { id } = where;
     await checkForValidData(data, id);
  }
};
```